# Linux CentOS YUM Error Package Requires - libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.1_EC)(64bit)

Tags: linux, openssl, centos, yum

I'm getting errors when I try to do a "yum update" that I'm unsure how to resolve. Below is the error message:

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: nginx-1.4.7-1.el6.ngx.x86_64 (nginx)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.1_EC)(64bit)
```

When I try to upgrade (which I believe is the best step forward) it these me there is "nothing to do" - like using the following line:

like:

```
sudo yum reinstall openssl
```

or:

```
sudo yum install http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/openssl-1.0.1e-15.el6.x86_64.rpm

Examining /var/tmp/yum-root-qbBKfF/openssl-1.0.1e-15.el6.x86_64.rpm: openssl-1.0.1e-15.el6.x86_64
/var/tmp/yum-root-qbBKfF/openssl-1.0.1e-15.el6.x86_64.rpm: does not update installed package.
Error: Nothing to do
```

I have tried cleaning out the YUM database

```
rpm -e --justdb --nodeps openssl
```

and

```
sudo rpm -ivh --force http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6.5/updates/x86_64/Packages/openssl-1.0.1e-16.el6_5.4.x86_64.rpm
```

and these both appear to put on the required packages when I run "rpm -q --provides openssl" however I then get this error message in YUM:

```
sudo yum update
There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

   /lib64/libcrypto.so.10: version `OPENSSL_1.0.1_EC' not found (required by /usr/lib64/libssl.so.10)

Please install a package which provides this module, or
verify that the module is installed correctly.

It's possible that the above module doesn't match the
current version of Python, which is:
2.6.9 (unknown, Feb 24 2014, 11:42:49)
[GCC 4.6.3 20120306 (Red Hat 4.6.3-2)]

If you cannot solve this problem yourself, please go to
the yum faq at:
  http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/Faq
```

Can anyone suggest anyother things I should try?

I can't seem to update, force an update, clean Yum DB and reinstall. The clean DB and Force do get the package on but them YUM can't find what OPENSSL_1.0.1_EC package it needs.

I tried upgrading with these 2 packages:

```
http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6.5/updates/x86_64/Packages/openssl-1.0.1e-16.el6_5.4.x86_64.rpm
http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/openssl-1.0.1e-15.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: From the Cent OS forums: [Tried to update OpenSSL, everything is now broken](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=44075).

Comment: Yes that article was good - found I to had to swap a file after a force upgrade and it all worked... thx

Answer (score 3):

you seem to have non-stock openssl packages installed (perhaps ptudor's?) they do NOT PROVIDE OPENSSL_1.0.1_EC since he drops openssl-1.0.1e/version.map.fips-ec entirely.

One possible fix is to add the provide to the custom openssl packages of yours this way:

```
--- openssl-1.0.1e-version.patch        2014-06-06 11:52:55.772046103 +0200
+++ new_openssl-1.0.1e-version.patch    2014-06-06 11:52:40.854045438 +0200
@@ -61,4 +61,12 @@
 +          _original*;
 +          _current*;
 +};
++OPENSSL_1.0.1_EC {
++    global:
++           EC*;
++};
```

should add the required PROVIDE to the lib. I offered that solution to him but he did not like it.

https://github.com/ptudor/centos6-openssl/issues/4

Or else you have to rebuild the nginx packages to link against your custom openssl.

Comment: For anyone who is experiencing this issue in the future I suggest first going to https://github.com/ptudor/centos6-openssl and rebuilding your openssl binaries.  I assume ptudor will accept my pull request in which case there is a tutorial for openssl-1.0.1i

Comment: Is there any update on this issue? The links in this answer and above comment are broken?